# Multiple identity providers for Office 365/Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, federated-identity

We have multiple domains on our Office 365 tenant. I would like to know if it is possible to use multiple identity providers (e.g. Okta or PingIdentity) within one Office 365 tenant - one identity provider per domain. So, users in DomainA.com would authenticate using Azure AD. And users in DomainB.com would authenticate using Okta.

Has anyone tried or had any experience doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can have a different IdP for each domain mapped to your Office 365 tenant.